# How to randomly generate a binary tree given the node number?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

```
//Definition for a binary tree node.

public class TreeNode {
    int key;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode(int x) { key = x; }
}
```

Given the total number of TreeNode  `int` `n`, how to generate a randomly distributed binary tree(I mean the **random** shape of binary tree, **not** the random key value. You can set all key values of TreeNodes equal to 1) and return the TreeNode `root`.

That is how to implement the following API:

```
public class RandomBinaryTree{
    public TreeNode binaryTreeGenerator(int n){

    }
}
```

PS: For example, `n = 3`, I want the algorithm can **randomly generate one of the following `5` binary trees each time**:

```
     1      1        1           1          1
    /      /        / \           \          \
   1      1        1   1           1          1
  /        \                      /            \
 1          1                    1              1
```

Is there any algorithm to generate binary trees **equiprobably** with fixed number of nodes `n`?

Comment: What random distribution do you need the tree shape to have?

Comment: Your tree needs a root. Start at root and recursively add the remaining nodes. Each layer will have twice many nodes as parent. Use a little bit of math to determine the amount of layers n will produce if needed.

Comment: the only thing coming to mind is, while doing insertion, use a random number generator to decide whether to turn left or right on the way down to leaf node

Comment: Is the TreeNode number, `n`, the number of nodes the tree is supposed to contain?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes.

Comment: @maplemaple The question is interesting. Can you please provide an example? I might have an approach for similar kind of question.

Comment: @maplemaple check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Biased distribution, simple algorithm

Starting from the root, randomly choose the number of nodes in each subtree, then recurse :

```
public class RandomBinaryTree {
    private Random random = new Random();

    public TreeNode binaryTreeGenerator(int n, int key){
        if (n == 0)
            return null;

        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(key);

        // Number of nodes in the left subtree (in [0, n-1])
        int leftN = random.nextInt(n);

        // Recursively build each subtree
        root.setLeft(binaryTreeGenerator(leftN, key));
        root.setRight(binaryTreeGenerator(n - leftN - 1, key));

        return root;
    }
}
```

This algorithm does not enforce uniform distribution of results and will heavily favor balanced trees. For a simple proof, consider the case `n = 3` and calculate probability of occurence for each of the 5 possible binary trees (see [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) for the related combinatorics).

### Uniform distribution, more challenging

There has been some research on this subject and [this](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/mike/Papers/RandomGeneration/RandomBinaryTrees.pdf) is probably one of the simplest and fastest methods (in *O(n)*). The idea is to generate a random word containing left and right brackets in equal numbers, then map that to a binary tree using a transformation that preserves uniform distribution.

**Step 1 :** Generate a random *balanced word* :

```
private static Random random = new Random();

// true means '(', false means ')'
private static boolean[] buildRandomBalancedWord(int n) {
    boolean[] word = new boolean[n * 2];
    List<Integer> positions = IntStream.range(0, 2 * n).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = random.nextInt(n + i);
        word[positions.remove(index)] = true;
    }
    return word;
}
```

**Step 2 :** The generated word may have `k` "defects", which are basically unmatched closing brackets. The paper shows that there is a way to rearrange the generated word such that the resulting mapping is a bijection from the set of words with `k` defects to the set of words with `0` defects (*well-formed words*). Here is the procedure :

```
private static void rearrange(boolean[] word, int start, int end) {
    int sum = 0;
    int defectIndex = -1;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        sum = sum + (word[i] ? 1 : -1);
        if (defectIndex < 0 && sum < 0) {
            defectIndex = i;
        } else if (defectIndex >= 0 && sum == 0) {
            // We now have irreducible u = rtl spanning [defectIndex, i]
            int uLength = i - defectIndex + 1;
            boolean[] flipped = new boolean[uLength - 2];
            for (int j = 0; j < flipped.length; j++)
                flipped[j] = !word[defectIndex + j + 1];

            // Shift the remaining word
            if (i + 1 < end)
                System.arraycopy(word, i + 1, word, defectIndex + 1, end - (i + 1));

            // Rewrite uw as lwrt*, t* being the flipped array
            word[defectIndex] = true;
            System.arraycopy(flipped, 0, word, end - flipped.length, flipped.length);
            word[end - uLength + 1] = false;

            // Now recurse on w, worst case we go (word.length/2)-deep
            rearrange(word, defectIndex + 1, end - uLength + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3 :** There is a one-to-one mapping from well-formed bracket words to binary trees : every pair of matching brackets is a node, everything inside is the left subtree, and everything after is the right subtree :

```
// There is probably a smarter way to do this
public static TreeNode buildTree(boolean[] word, int key) {
    Deque<TreeNode> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    boolean insertRight = false;
    TreeNode root = null;
    TreeNode currentNode = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (word[i]) {
            TreeNode previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = new TreeNode(key);

            if (root == null) {
                root = currentNode;
            } else if (insertRight) {
                previousNode.setRight(currentNode);
                insertRight = false;
            } else {
                previousNode.setLeft(currentNode);
            }

            stack.push(currentNode);
        } else {
            currentNode = stack.pop();
            insertRight = true;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

**Some utility functions** :

```
public static boolean[] buildRandomWellFormedWord(int n) {
    boolean[] word = buildRandomBalancedWord(n);
    rearrange(word, 0, word.length);
    return word;
}

public static String toString(boolean[] word) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (boolean b : word)
        str.append(b ? "(" : ")");
    return str.toString();
}
```

**Test** : Let's print the actual distribution over 10 millions runs of size 3 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int N = 10000000, n = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        boolean[] word = buildRandomWellFormedWord(n);
        String str = toString(word);
        Integer count = counts.get(str);
        if (count == null)
            count = 0;
        counts.put(str, count + 1);
    }

    counts.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> 
        System.out.println("P[" + e.getKey() + "] = " + e.getValue().doubleValue() / N));
}
```

The output should look something like :

```
P[()()()] = 0.200166
P[(()())] = 0.200451
P[()(())] = 0.199894
P[((()))] = 0.199006
P[(())()] = 0.200483
```

So `buildTree(buildRandomWellFormedWord(n), key)` will yield a binary tree of size `n` following a uniform distribution over all possible trees.

Comment: I will also suggest the reader to look at [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), which gives the number of non-isomorphic trees having n nodes.  And, I think trees generated by your algorithm have equal probability, given that your random function isn't  biased.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but it does not guarantee equal probability though. For that, you need to keep track of number of nodes occurring to left of any given node. Based on that, you can decide that and make it an unbiased generator.

Comment: @mrpandey it turns out this algorithm does not give all combinations uniformly when nodes are interchangeable : with `n = 3`, the balanced tree has probability `1/3`, but there are 5 possible trees. However the approach does seem to work when distributing a set of *unique* nodes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_binary_tree#Random_split_trees).

Comment: @Arminius Thank you so much for your great answer.

Answer (score 0):

generating a random number from the binary tree may be easy if other key considerations have to be overlooked, such as randomness and equal probability. For simplicity, the code below randomly generates a node from a tree where each node has an equal probability to be selected.

Binary tree in python

```
import random
class BinaryTree:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.value = value
            self.left_size = 0
            self.right_size = 0

    def insert(self, value, root):
        node = BinaryTree.Node(value)

        if value <= root.value:
             root.left_size += 1
             if root.left == None:
                 root.left = node
             else:
                 self.insert(value, root.left)
        else:
            root.right_size += 1
            if root.right == None:
                root.right = node
            else:
                self.insert(value, root.right)

    def display(self, root):
        if root == None:
           return;
        self.display(root.left)
        print(root.value, end =" ")
        self.display(root.right)
    

def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.count = 0


def insert(self, value):
    if self.root == None:
        self.root = BinaryTree.Node(value)
        return
    self.root.insert(value, self.root)
    self.count += 1

def size(self):
    return self.count
def display(self):
    if self.root == None:
        return;
    self.root.display(self.root)
    

def get_random_node(self):
    """
    Generate a random number r {1....N} where r is the total number of 
    elemnts
    calculate the total number of elements in a binarytree
    if r == count then return the current node
    if r > (count+left) check on the right i.e recursively getchild(1, r-count- node.left_size, node.right)
    else getchild (count +1, r, node.left)
    Calculate the number of children on the left
    """
    if self.size() == 1:
        return self.root
    r = random.randint(1, self.size() + 1)
    return self.getchild(1, r, self.root)

def getchild(self, count, r, node):
    if r == count:
        return node
    if r > (count + node.left_size):
        return self.getchild(1, (r - count-node.left_size), node.right)
    return self.getchild(count + 1, r, node.left)
```